# How to duplicate entries

Tags: entries

How do I duplicate content within craft?

I created one article, and dont want to copy paste content from one to the other, or use one article as template for the others.

Comment: Right now I think that's your only option. Short of writing a plugin to do it?

Answer (score 16):

When viewing an entry, click the arrow on the save button and you'll see an option to "Save as new entry". This duplicates the entry and you can immediately begin editing the new entry.

I'm not sure if this is what you mean by "use one article as template for the others" or not. It seems you can either manually create a new entry and then copy and paste content, or use this method.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Worth mentioning, this feature was introduced in [Craft 2.3](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2615) (released Dec. 2, 2014... four months after this question was originally asked).

Comment: Strange, I have craft 2.4 and it is only letting me save and continue or save as a draft on the arrow? Is there some place you have to go to enable this feature?

Comment: @Matt That sounds either like a bug, or at least a brand new question. I'd suggest either [posting a new question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) (with screenshots and additional details), or reporting it directly to support@buildwithcraft.com

Comment: Can anyone confirm this is a bug or just not supported