# Is it possible to duplicate a entry as a draft entry?

Tags: plugin-development, entry

I need a function to duplicate an (published) entry as a draft entry. Now if I duplicate an entry it will immediately publics that entry an that fires some plugin events (sends mails) I didn't want.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following 100%, but it sounds like you want to duplicate an entry and have it set to disabled by default?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English I meant a draft entry not a concept entry (that's how we call it in Holland). The client publish a entry and after that he want to duplicate that published entry but as a draft and not immediately publish it because the client want to make some changes first and then publish the duplicated entry. After publishing a plugin sends a mail to all users. Therefore it should not be published immediately.

Comment: No worries, Maarten... it'd definitely need to be done through a plugin and [Brad](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/20149/57) answer is a good starting point.

Comment: Is there any better/simpler solution to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [How can I copy an entry?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11969/how-can-i-copy-an-entry)

Just change:

```
$newEntry->enabled = $oldEntry->enabled;
```

to

```
$newEntry->enabled = false;
```

To start out building your own plugin: https://pluginfactory.io/, be sure to select the Services lightswitch.